# Decoding a JSON array with a KEY in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the below valid JSON that has the key `best_images` that is causing my problems.

```
$json_array =  {
 "best_images": 
     [{
        "id": "1",
        "Title": "My Image 1",
        "Photographer": "Kate Doe",
        "Album": "Album 1",
        "Imagefilename": "image1.jpg",
        "Year": "2005",
        "Size": "1.91 MB"

    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Title": "My Image 2",
        "Photographer": "Jermaine Kavme",
        "Album": "Album 2",
        "Imagefilename": "image2.jpg",
        "Year": "2012",
        "Size": "5.13 MB"

    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "Title": "My Image 4",
        "Photographer": "Kate Doe2",
        "Album": "Album 4",
        "Imagefilename": "image4.jpg",
        "Year": "2012",
        "Size": "1.31 MB"

    }
    ]
}
```

I want to decode it, and I am using the following method:

$obj = json_decode($json_string, true); 
however, when I use the below code to get the keys, I am getting one the `best_images` key and not the rest.

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) 
{     
echo $key;    
}
```

How can I get the deeper than the first big key (what is it called actually) to reach the below keys?

Also, how can I separate each inner object so that I can put each one in database row?

Comment: Nested foreach loops

Answer (score 4):

Use this as you know the 1st array key is "best_image":

```
foreach ($obj["best_image"] as $key => $value) 
{     
  echo $key;    
}
```

Otherwise you need to loop it twice.

```
 foreach ($obj["best_image"] as $mainkey => $arrObj) 
     foreach ($arrObj as $key => $value) 
     {     
       echo $key;   
     } 
 }
}
```

Comment: don't forget an `if (isset($obj['best_image']))` condition :p if it's an API you may never know what comes in :O

Comment: I will suggest you check !empty() check before each foreach()

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive function:

```
function show_arr_r($arr, $level=0)
{
   foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
      for ($x=0; $x<$level $x++) print '.';
      print "$k="; 
      if (is_array($v)) {
         print "\n";
         show_arr($k, $level+1);
      } else {
         print $k . "\n";
      }
   }
 }
```

Or use print_r, or var_export.

But usually you want to *do* something with the data - you reference deeper array elements simply by adding more []:

```
if ($obj["best_images"][1]["Photographer"]=="Kate Doe") {
```

Or...

```
if ($obj->best_images[1]->Photographer=="Kate Doe") {
```